# @HTML.DropDownList displaying names instead of ID

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-select

I'm new to MVC and I'm currently learning it for my future. I'm having a problem with @Html.DropDownList.
I want it to display ID, not names but it doesn't display as I wanted to.

## View code

```
      <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ID_KH, "ID_KH", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownList("ID_KH", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ID_KH, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
```

[My current problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbDSz.png)

I want my DropDownList to display IDs, not names or anything. Can someone help me please, thank you very much. And ID_KH is a foreign key that i made to another table. It does recognize and read that ID from another table so I really want to display that ID, not the name

Answer (score 0):

You can using map your **ModelData**

```
ViewBag.ID_KH = yourData.Select(a=> new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = a.Id, // change for which filed want to display
        Value = a.Id
    });
```